# Pink gatorade turned bluish purple by thick clear liquid

Tags: everyday-chemistry

If I had two teaspoons of pink strawberry gatorade and one teaspoon of a clear thick liquid and when mixed together it turned bluish purple in a chemical reaction, what might the thick clear liquid be?

Comment: "Quick questions" without elaboration effort are not very welcome, and may be closed. Always think about and search for possible answers thoroughly before posting a question.

Comment: Someone had me drink a toxic chemical under false pretenses. I didn't consider proper website etiquette. I do apologize.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, many dyes, natural or artificial, change color with changing pH ( acidity ).  Natural anthocyan dyes are usually about red in acidic, about blue/violet in alkaline solutions. You can e.g. check red beetroot juice when washing soda is added. So that clear solution was probably an alkaline solution. These reactions are reversible, if pH is returned to a out initial value, the initial color will return.

Comment: That is most likely the case and plus 1. I want to add that bleach can also cause colour changes or various colours to appear based not only on the pH but on oxidative reactions. In most cases the latter processes results in discolouration but sometimes not.

Comment: @Alchimista But as bleach is alkaline, if discoloration did not occur, the colour change would happen even for the pH change itself.

Comment: Well, sure. Just pointing to a different mechanism not (entirely at least) based on pH.

Answer (score 1):

It does not have to be a full-fledged alkali to generate this color change effect.  Alkaline earths work quite well (and less hazardously) even with only limited or sparing solubility.  For a neat-looking demonstration with magnesia (or more accurately, the hydroxide it produces in water), see the picture and do the experiment [here](https://www.stevespanglerscience.com/lab/experiments/color-changing-milk-of-magnesia/).

Comment: Alkaline vs acidic is the only info I can gather from the chemical reaction I saw?

Comment: Like that, based on the only info we were provided with. For more, we would need the fortune-teller crystal ball to tell.